# When to use WCF data services and when not?

Tags: .net, wcf-ria-services, wcf-data-services

For which applications or development scenarios the usage of **WCF Data Services** makes sense and when other technolgies are the better choice (for example WCF RIA Services, ADO Entity Framework, classical ADO.NET, simple services or whatever) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WCF Data Services is a pretty easy and quick way to get your data model - collections and entities - out on the web. You can easily browse your collections, look at entities etc., all through standard HTTP / REST calls.

As long as you have mostly that - showing and displaying entities and collections of entities - it works really well. I don't really know the extra bonus that WCF RIA Services carry just yet - haven't investigated that too much.

WCF Data Services are based on a model representation of your data - that's where Linq-to-SQL or Entity Framework come into play and allow you to create that model, based on your physical database.

When you need to use something like method-oriented services, however - like "Insert customer", "Calculate total orders for customer" and so forth, then a SOAP-based WCF service will be more suited. A SOAP based WCF service defines a service contract (set of methods on your service) and allows you to call those methods on your service object.

SOAP is great when doing transaction-oriented business work - it's self-describing, e.g. your client can discover and interrogate the SOAP service (an area where REST sorely lacks - there's no "WSDL" or something comparable for REST services).

And if you're doing SOAP, I would also recommend using a model-based approach for your data - create a model of your database and expose methods on those entities to the outside world - again, using Linq-to-SQL, Entity Framework, NHibernate or some other modelling / ORM tool. I would not advise to use "classical" or "bare-bones" ADO.NET for most of your work - it's just too much grunt work and silly code - let a framework like Linq-to-SQL or EF handle that boring infrastructure stuff for you and concentrate on your actual business requirements and needs.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer.